# Why is my div inheriting height from something that isn't its parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage that has a recurring design element of an inset border surrounding a `<div>` of content. The inset border is done with LESS/CSS, and is itself a `<div class="inset-border">` placed after the content but within a wrapper.

It's an approach that's working well for almost the entire page. However, there's one section where the border isn't inheriting its dimensions from the parent wrapper, but rather it's great-grandparent element. Why?

The rendered CSS for the border:

```
.inset-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffc174;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 4%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The troublesome HTML:

```
<div class="update-container">
  <div class="update-div">
      <span class="small-title">Latest Updates</span>
      <h2 class="slogan">@Html.Raw(title)</h2>
      <a class="updates-button" href="@link">@buttonText</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inset-border"></div>
```

And an instance of usage where it's working correctly:

```
<div class="whitebox-about">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left:0">
      <h2 class="slogan-right">@Html.Raw(rightblurb)</h2>
  </div>
...
  <div class="inset-border"></div>
</div>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Position absolute will position the element outside of its parent. Try setting position relative to the parent to constrain the element. `.update-container {position: relative;}`

Comment: Note: at the end of the `troublesome html`, there is a matching closing div tag. It's not rendering in the question, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @m.spyratos That did it! If you care to submit it as a full answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set position to the parent element.

```
.update-container {
    position: relative;
}
```

---

For more details, check [MDN - Absolute Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Absolute_positioning).

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static).

This means, that in order to position your element relatively to its parent you need to set a position to the parent.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now the child element will be positioned relative to its parent. We could use any position value instead of relative (except static), but usually relative is preferred as it positions the element relatively to itself, thus the layout does not change.